# Adding page breaks to d3 visualization based on group id

Tags: javascript, pdf, d3.js

I am currently running into an issue relating to adding page breaks when my html file renders into a pdf.

Currently, I have a function that generates a scatterplot with the format below:

```
function createScatterplot(row, column, group) {
    ## any d3 visualization code goes here
}
```

By calling:

```
createScatterplot(feature1, feature2, 'a')
createScatterplot(feature2, feature3, 'a')
createScatterplot(feature1, feature3, 'b')
```

it will generate three scatterplots using the d3.js library. Is there an easy way to add page breaks so that we get the following output:

```
createScatterplot(feature1, feature2, 'a')
createScatterplot(feature2, feature3, 'a')
<--- Page break here --->
createScatterplot(feature1, feature3, 'b')
```

where each page break is determined by the group (third parameter of the function)?

I know that the function createScatterplot generates an SVG object, but when attempting to use the existing solutions for page breaks in CSS, it seems that the creation of the svg object follows after the execution of the page breaks.

Ideally, I wouldn't want to use any additional JS library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SVG does not do page breaks, but here is a link to an approach that may work for you: https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/details/jKxJz/

The idea is "re-using the same graphic within multiple SVG elements, using the viewBox attribute to define which part of the graphic should be visible each time". It's a little complicated, but if you look at the codepen, pay attention to the css, especially the "screen styles" part, you can get it to work. Here's a somewhat abridged version - in Chrome (haven't tested with others) when you Print the page it divides it into 4 page-sized blocks...

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>paginate</title>
    <style>
        figure.svg-container {
            display: block;
            overflow: scroll;
            max-width: 90vw;
            max-height: 90vh;
            border:gray solid thin;
        }
        svg.print {
            display: none;
        }
        @media print {
            figure.svg-container {
                display: inline;
                overflow: auto;
                border: none;
            }
            svg.screen {
                display: none;
            }
            svg.print {
                overflow: hidden;
                border: thin lightgray solid;
                padding: 0.5em;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                break-inside: avoid;
            }
        }
        @media print and (orientation: landscape){
            svg.print.landscape {
                display: block;
                height: 7in;
                width: 10in;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <figure class="svg-container">
        <svg class="screen" width="18in" height="12in" viewBox="0 0 1800 1200">
            <g id="graphic"></g>
        </svg>
        <!-- For printing in landscape mode, the graphic is divided into four
        overlapping quadrants which will each fit on a letter/A4 page without scaling.  
        The 1000*700 viewBox is equivalent to 10in*7in of the onscreen dimensions. -->
        <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="0 0 1000 700">
            <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
            <defs>
                <symbol id="arrow-left" overflow="visible"
                    viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
                    <!-- left-pointing block arrow pointing to 0,0 point -->
                    <path class="arrow" d="M0 0L5 -5, 5 -3, 12 -3, 12 3, 5 3, 5 5Z" />
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="arrow-right" overflow="visible"
                    viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
                    <!-- right-pointing block arrow pointing to 0,0 point -->
                    <path class="arrow" transform="rotate(180)"
                    d="M0 0L5 -5, 5 -3, 12 -3, 12 3, 5 3, 5 5Z" />
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="arrow-top" overflow="visible"
                    viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
                    <!-- top-pointing block arrow pointing to 0,0 point -->
                    <path class="arrow" transform="rotate(90)"
                    d="M0 0L5 -5, 5 -3, 12 -3, 12 3, 5 3, 5 5Z" />
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="arrow-bottom" overflow="visible"
                    viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
                    <!-- bottom-pointing block arrow pointing to 0,0 point -->
                    <path class="arrow" transform="rotate(-90)"
                    d="M0 0L5 -5, 5 -3, 12 -3, 12 3, 5 3, 5 5Z" />
                </symbol>
            </defs>
            <g class="labels">
                <text class="label" x="50%" y="50%">A</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-right" x="100%" y="50%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer right" x="100%" y="50%" dx="-50">B</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-bottom" x="50%" y="100%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer bottom" x="50%" y="100%" dy="-50">C</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="800 0 1000 700">
            <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
            <g class="labels" transform="translate(800,0)">
                <text class="label" x="50%" y="50%">B</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-left" x="0%" y="50%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer left" x="0%" y="50%" dx="50">A</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-bottom" x="50%" y="100%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer bottom" x="50%" y="100%" dy="-50">D</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="0 500 1000 700">
            <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
            <g class="labels" transform="translate(0,500)">
                <text class="label" x="50%" y="50%">C</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-right" x="100%" y="50%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer right" x="100%" y="50%" dx="-50">D</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-top" x="50%" y="0%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer top" x="50%" y="0%" dy="50">A</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="800 500 1000 700">
            <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
            <g class="labels" transform="translate(800,500)">
                <text class="label" x="50%" y="50%">D</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-left" x="0%" y="50%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer left" x="0%" y="50%" dx="50">C</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-top" x="50%" y="0%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer top" x="50%" y="0%" dy="50">B</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <!-- For printing in portrait mode, the graphic is scaled down slightly
        to fit on two pages.  Again, the content of each page will  overlap slightly. -->
        <svg class="print portrait" viewBox="0 0 1000 1200">
            <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
            <g class="labels">
                <text class="label" x="50%" y="50%">A</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-right" x="100%" y="50%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer right" x="100%" y="50%" dx="-50">B</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg class="print portrait" viewBox="800 0 1000 1200">
            <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
            <g class="labels" transform="translate(800,0)">
                <text class="label" x="50%" y="50%">B</text>
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-left" x="0%" y="50%" width="100" height="100" />
                <text class="pointer left" x="0%" y="50%" dx="50">A</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </figure>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            var doc = document;
            var g = doc.getElementById("graphic");
            var svgNS = g.namespaceURI;
            var r, t;
            for (var i=0; i<18; i++) {
                for (var j=0; j<12; j++) {
                    r = doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
                    r.setAttribute("width", "80");
                    r.setAttribute("height", "80");
                    r.setAttribute("x", (i*100 + 10));
                    r.setAttribute("y", (j*100 + 10));
                    r.style.setProperty("fill-opacity", ((i*j + 1)%20)/20, null);
                    g.insertBefore(r, null);
                    t = doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "text");
                    t.setAttribute("x", (i*100 + 50));
                    t.setAttribute("y", (j*100 + 50));
                    t.setAttribute("class", "diagram");
                    t.textContent = [i,j];
                    g.insertBefore(t, null);
                }  
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```